# Getting the width of html content inside an LI that's 100% wide

Tags: jquery, css

In my snippet, my OL has a CSS width of 100%. In my jQuery I want to get the width (like offsetWidth in vanilla JS) of the content inside the LI tag, but the jQuery `width()` returns the width of the LI, which ends up being the full width of the browser (instead of around 140 pixels).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    alert($("#theOl li:eq(0)").width());
});
```

```css
#theOl {
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="theOl">
  <li>This is some text
</ol>
```

Note, that I need the LI itself to remain at 100% width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not wrap the `<li>` content in a span, and simply get the width of that?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    alert($("#theOl li:eq(0) span").width());
});
```

```css
#theOl {
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="theOl">
  <li><span>This is some text</span>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround for what I'm trying to achieve!

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to wrap your li content with an inline-block element and get this element's width, otherwise you'll be getting the li element width that is a list-item and occupies 100% of it's parent's width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the: `display: inline-block` or `inline` to the `li` in your CSS. I just added directly into the HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    alert($("#theOl li:eq(0)").width());
});
```

```css
#theOl {
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="theOl">
  <li style="display: inline-block">This is some text</li>
</ol>
```

This happens because by default the element has the `block` display and that makes to use the entire space of the container.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only HTML5, then something like this could be used:

```
function getTextWidth(text) {
    var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas ||
        (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return (context.measureText(text).width);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    var content  = $("#theOl li:eq(0)").html();
    alert(getTextWidth(content));
})
```

See the fiddle  here :  https://jsfiddle.net/7Lxuf285/1/

One improvement can be done by passing the font size in the method and setting it in the context.

```
 context.font = font;
```

See the fiddle with font : https://jsfiddle.net/7Lxuf285/2/